# Поиск элемента в дереве(ошибка)

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Подскажите, плиз. Делаю поиск в дереве, нахожу и возвращаю указатель, а он выдаёт ошибку. Компилятор Dev-C++.

```
Node* SearchNode(Node* tree, std::string str) { 
 if(!tree) 
       return NULL; 
 else if(tree->name == str) 
       return tree;    
 else if(str < tree->name) 
        SearchNode(tree->left, str); 
  else 
        SearchNode(tree->right, str);}
```

Comment: Не хватает return для рекурсивных вызовов. Да и строку я бы по ссылке передавал бы, так как к примеру, если строка большая и дерево тоже, вполне будет возможно переполнение стэка, из-за большого количества копий...

Answer (score 6):

Все пути выполнения не-`void` функции в С++ должны заканчиваться `return` (или `throw`, как заметил, @acade):

```
Node* SearchNode(Node* tree, std::string str) 
{ 
  if (!tree) 
    return NULL; 
  else if (tree->name == str) 
    return tree;    
  else if (str < tree->name) 
    return SearchNode(tree->left, str); 
  else 
    return SearchNode(tree->right, str);
}
```

В противном случае - поведение не определено. (Исключением из этого правила является только функция `main`).

Передача параметра `str` "по ссылке" `const std::string &str`, вместо передачи "по значению" - хорошая и правильная идея, но это не более чем оптимизация, на работоспособность кода не влияющая.

P.S. Как ни странно, исправление `std::string str` на `const std::string &str` может неожиданно сделать ваш исходный вариант внешне "работоспособным", несмотря на отсутствующие `return` в третьей и четвертой ветке. Но это не более чем хорошо известный наведенный эффект, случайное проявление неопределенного поведения.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: _Все пути выполнения не-void функции в С++ должны заканчиваться return_ - или `throw`

Comment: @acade: Да, верное уточнение. Или `throw`.

Comment: @AnT, но  с  const std::string &str и без  return в  ветках, всеравно компилятор должен выдать предупреждение, или не все компиляторы выдают такое предупреждение?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Язык не требует от компиляторов никакой диагностики в этом случае. Просто поведение не определено.

Comment: @AnT, думаю  язык вообше не требует  любого вида предупреждения от компилятора. Но  ваш ответ означает, что могут быть компиляторы, не выдавшие такое предупреждение, правильно я вас понел?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: В языке нет понятия "предупреждения", а есть лишь понятие "диагностического сообщения". Все сообщения компилятора попадают в эту категорию. Правила языка делятся на диагностируемые и недиагностируемые. При нарушении диагностируемых правил *требуется* диагностическое сообщение (любое). Нарушение недиагностируемых правил не требует сообщения, но приводит к UB. Данное правило является недиагностируемым. Однако UB может приводить в т.ч. и к диагностическому сообщению во время компиляции, и к отказу компилировать программу.

Answer (score 5):

Вам уже указали на вашу ошибку. Я от себя добавлю, что лучше функцию написать иначе. Поскольку, рекурсивный вызов функции довольно дорого обходится по времени выполнения. Кроме этого код у вас получается многословным. 
А можно написать например так:

```
Node* SearchNode(Node* tree, const std::string& str) { 
    while (tree && tree->name != str) 
        tree = str < tree->name ? tree->left : tree->right;
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример